ruamel.yaml: use double quotes in YAML created with `YAML.dump()`
It seems there is a preserve_quotes attribute which can be used when working with an already ruamel.yaml-parsed YAML file.
However, what I have is a Python dictionary (to be precise, I have a pydantic model which I'm converting to a dict) which I need to write into a YAML file.
So far, the only solution I could think of is to recursively walk the dict and cast all the string values to DoubleQuotedScalarString. This seems to be suboptimal. Is there some way to enable this behavior "globally" (as a config setting, attribute of the main YAML instance, etc.)?
What it does
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys

yaml = YAML()
d = {"a": "b", "b": 'c', "c": "", "d": '', "e": {"x": "y", "y": ""}}

yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout)

produces:
a: b
b: c
c: ''
d: ''
e:
  x: y
  y: ''

What I'm looking for
yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout)

produces:
a: b
b: c
c: ""
d: ""
e:
  x: y
  y: ""

I have tried to adapt the suggestion from this answer to ruamel.yaml, but it doesn't work:
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys

def double_quotes_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar("tag:yaml.org,2002:str", data, style="")

yaml = YAML()
yaml.representer.add_representer(str, double_quotes_representer)
d = {"a": "b", "b": 'c', "c": "", "d": '', "e": {"x": "y", "y": ""}}

yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout)

a: b
b: c
c: ''
d: ''
e:
  x: y
  y: ''

